# IPSec VPN on Vista

Tags: vpn, windows-vista, ipsec, ipcop

My company uses IPCop to configure it's VPN.  We have an IPSec script that runs on Windows XP to open a connection using a security certificate for authentication.  Microsoft totally changed things around with Vista, and our script no longer works.  Has anyone set up a Vista VPN connection, specifically to connect with IPCop on the other end?

We've found [TheGreenBow VPN Client](http://www.thegreenbow.com/vpn.html), but we'd prefer something cheaper, like free.

Comment: Not used IPCop, but these links may help. http://www.publicvpn.com/support/Vista.php http://www.cuhk.edu.hk/itsc/network/vpn/winvista.html

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the [OpenVPN 2.1_rc15](http://openvpn.net/index.php/downloads.html).  I found an article that may lead you through the steps to get it working.

http://bubbazanetti.blogspot.com/2008/11/openvpn-ipcop-and-vista.html

Comment: OpenVPN is an *awesome* tool.  In fact, it's what we used to connect 500 machines at my previous job, and it's what I use at home for VPN purposes.  However, if they have an existing VPN setup based on IPSec, OpenVPN might not be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Vista uses a different command-line tool for managing IPsec connections. Check out the [netsh ipsec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739580.aspx) command and you should be able to get your script running (it might help if you posted excerpts from it here, too).